# Php sql injection protection

Tags: php

I am using mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['page']) in my code. Is it able to prevent SQL Injection in my php code else i will have to do more protection ?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, it isn't. mysql_real_escape_string will help with strings only

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) are better.

Comment: It is much harder to accidentally fail to convert a variable if you are doing it as part of prepared statement syntax then if you are concatenating half a dozen variables into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would drop the `mysql` extension and migrate to the `mysqli` extension. The problem with the `mysql` extension is that its old, and quite frankly, its rather easy to forget to escape something.

`mysqli` has support for [prepared statements](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and it also has an OOP API which makes it way easier to develop.

When you start using [prepared statements](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare), it makes it easier to keep track of your parameters. It also auto escapes them for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using prepared statements in most cases, but it's only necessary when inserting data that came from a user that could be a string. Prepared statements are more expensive (performance), so when you can avoid them you probably should. There are many benefits of using prepared statements and/or database transactions. You should probably look into it, unless you already have.

If you receive numerical values from, for example, a form, you just need to ensure data quality by converting the input into a number (any input from GET or POST are ALWAYS regarded as strings by PHP, unless you convert them), and any malicious code will be removed.

Here's an example:

```
$intCarAge = (int) $_POST['car_age'];
mysqli_query("UPDATE cars SET car_age = " . $intCarAge . " WHERE id = '123' ");
```

The "(int)" converts the data in the input variable $_POST['car_age'] to a number (integer). It can be added before any variable in your code. Any letters inside the variable will be removed and any numbers will be kept. [You can read more about number conversion here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Hope I was of any help!